# How to change UI property from other class in Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please let me know how to change UI property(ex. textblock, textbox, etc) from other class in Windows Phone 7 app?

My code image is like this:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //call other class method
        OtherClass a = new OtherClass();
        //Update method is executed different thread.
        a.Update();
    }
}
```

OtherClass.cs

```
public OtherClass
{
    //execute the method in async.
    Thread a = new Thread(new TreadStart(Update));
    a.Start();

    public static void Update()
    {
        //Can I do that?? (textBlock1 is MainPage's property.)
        textBlock1.Text = "abc";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well accessing GUI from other classess is not good application design. You should consider using MVVM design pattern. Then your "OtherClass" would become view model and view would use data binding to retrieve data.

If you still want use your approach then try using Singleton pattern with your MainPage.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use MVVM patern.

Answer (score 1):

First - I wish I had adopted MVVM and DataBinding from the start now it would be a PITA so if you haven't done much code yet better change to that official pattern..

If not, this is how I've done it now translated to your example:

UI-Thread on MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
..
a.Update(this); //this = reference to MainPage
```

OtherClass:
..

```
public static void Update(PhoneApplicationPage mainRef)
    {
     Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>      //this will async. execute in UI
        {((MainPage)mainRef).textBlock1.Text = "abc";} ); //casting mainRef to MainPage
    }                                                     //and access textBlock1
```

Think its ugly and I don't know if passing the MainPages Object is much overhead but it should be thread-save (thanks to the ..BeginInvoke)

Consider going for MVVM ;D

Frank